How can I edit the thumb to use a custom image (.png) in WPF?
I am working on creating an app which has a very specific looking GUI. My app contains TreeView which has a scrollbar. The scrollbar unfortunately is very basic and looks like your typical Windows scrollbar. I need it to match more closely to the UI textures that I am using in my app but cannot seem to figure out how to edit the Thumb correctly so that it will accept a .png.
The .xaml script
<Window x:Class="TestAPP.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAPP"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Register ScrollThumbConverter -->
        <local:ScrollThumbConverter x:Key="ScrollThumbConverter"/>
        <local:ThumbHeightConverter x:Key="ThumbHeightConverter" />

        <!-- Custom ScrollBar Style -->
        <Style x:Key="CustomScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,116">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!-- Up Arrow -->
                            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Height="15" Width="15"
                                          Click="UpArrow_Click"
                                          BorderThickness="0">
                                <RepeatButton.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/154965.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                </RepeatButton.Background>
                            </RepeatButton>

                            <!-- ScrollBar Track with MultiBinding -->
                            <Track Grid.Row="1" Name="PART_Track">
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb Height="50" Width="15" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
                                        <Thumb.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Image Source="/154971.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Thumb.Template>

                                        <!-- MultiBinding for thumb position -->
                                        <Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ScrollThumbConverter}">
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" Path="VerticalOffset" />
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" Path="ScrollableHeight" />
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" Path="ViewportHeight" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                    </Thumb>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                            </Track>

                            <!-- Down Arrow -->
                            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2" Height="15" Width="15"
                                          Click="DownArrow_Click"
                                          BorderThickness="0">
                                <RepeatButton.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/154964.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                </RepeatButton.Background>
                            </RepeatButton>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <!-- ScrollViewer with custom scrollbar -->
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged">
            <ScrollViewer.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource CustomScrollBar}" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ScrollViewer.Style>

            <!-- Example content to scroll -->
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Line 1" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Line 2" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Line 3" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Line 4" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Line 5" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Line 6" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Line 7" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Line 8" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Line 9" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Line 10" Height="50"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>

.xaml.cs script
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestAPP
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Scroll up when up arrow is clicked
        private void UpArrow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyScrollViewer.LineUp();  // Scroll one line up
        }

        // Scroll down when down arrow is clicked
        private void DownArrow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyScrollViewer.LineDown();  // Scroll one line down
        }

        // Handle scroll changes (you can manually adjust the thumb size or handle any visual logic here)
        private void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Optional: Add any additional logic to manage thumb movement or other scroll events.
        }
    }

    public class ScrollThumbConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length < 3 || !(values[0] is double verticalOffset) || !(values[1] is double scrollableHeight) || !(values[2] is double viewportHeight))
            {
                return new TranslateTransform(0, 0); // Default transform
            }

            // Calculate the thumb's position
            double trackHeight = scrollableHeight + viewportHeight; // Total track height
            double ratio = scrollableHeight > 0 ? verticalOffset / scrollableHeight : 0;
            double thumbPosition = ratio * (trackHeight - viewportHeight); // Calculate thumb position

            return new TranslateTransform(0, thumbPosition);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    
    public class ThumbHeightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length < 2 || !(values[0] is double viewportHeight) || !(values[1] is double scrollableHeight))
            {
                return 50.0; // Default thumb height if values are missing
            }

            // Calculate the thumb height as a ratio of the viewport to the total scrollable height
            double totalHeight = scrollableHeight + viewportHeight;
            double thumbHeight = (viewportHeight / totalHeight) * viewportHeight;

            return Math.Max(20, thumbHeight); // Ensure a minimum thumb height for usability
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

I am working .xaml (WPF) and C# btw. Below I have added a test version of the script I am working with. The arrows work and look exactly like I want but I cannot get the thumb to show up properly. What am I doing wrong?

The images should have their build action in the solution explorer set to "Resource" (right click on the image in the solution explorer and choose "Properties").  After doing that you'll want to run Build > Clean Solution.  It'll modify your csproj to include items that look like this:
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="154965.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="154965.png" />
  </ItemGroup>


They are set as a resource but not explicitly stated like that in the code. I will try that this evening. Thank you for taking the time to offer a solution!
